# Use second Ubuntu Desktop as external Monitor

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, virtualization

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my iMac and would like to use my other old iMac, also running Ubuntu 12.04, as an external Monitor. Functionally if I were to move my cursor to the extreme right, as you would if you had a second monitor, it would switch to the other iMac and would be using it.

Can't use TwinView as both computers are not NVidia based.

I used to have this functionality in WinXP and it worked quite nicely because the 'second monitor' could run intensive processes without interfering with my main computer because its running on a separate computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are separate computers, you cannot use anything like TwinView or Xinerama, as they are not separate monitors on the same computer.

You can however, use `synergy` or `x2x` to accomplish what you want to do. Using synergy is probably easier, and there is a simple GUI called `quicksynergy`, which you can install to make using it easier.